# dotnet publish: clean external output directory

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-cli

I would like to clean my external output folder before publish. The solution I have today is the following:

```
Remove-Item -Path ..\artifacts -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Recurse -Force;
dotnet publish ..\myproject.sln -c Release -o ..\artifacts\myproject;
```

Is there a better way to do this (without `Remove-Item`)? I've tried using `dotnet clean` and specifying the output folder but is not working.